# how to rspec test a class @@var value from ENV

Tags: ruby, rspec, environment-variables

I have a class that has a class variable @@var getting its value based on an ENV setting.  and a class method uses this @@var to perform a certain task.

However, I can't seem to be able to find a way to test this class method for the case where the ENV is set to the desired value.

Here are the code for the simplified class and spec test

```
class Doer
  @@master = (ENV.has_key?('MASTER') && ENV['MASTER'] == 'yes')

  def self.check_master
    @@master
  end
end
```

```
require_relative '../bin/doer'

describe Doer do
  describe '#check_master' do
    context 'env init' do

      it 'is set to yes' do
        stub_const('ENV', {'MASTER' => 'yes'})
        expect(Doer.check_master).to eq(true)
      end

      it 'is set to other value' do
        stub_const('ENV', {'MASTER' => 'no'})
        expect(Doer.check_master).to eq(false)
      end

      it 'is NOT set or unavailable' do
        expect(Doer.check_master).to eq(false)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: __Does__ it have to be a `@@class_variable`? Why not put that login in the `check_master` (memoized, if you worry about lookup costs)?

Comment: I thought about that as well if that's the only option.